# No extension Method ToList on a dbset - really though?

Tags: entity-framework

Background - I am using Entity framework code version 2.1.4-rtm-31024

check out the **CODE LISTING 1** - the problem (according to Ms Build Engine 15.9) is that GetAllMakes calls .ToList, but no 'ToList' method exists for a DbSet of VehicleMake. (check out **Code Listing 2**) to see the implementation of _vehicleContext.VehicleMakes

Why do I get a compile error? this makes no sense to me since I can call VehicleMakes.ToList() elsewhere in the code (no compiler error) no problem at all - **see listing 3** for an example.

**CODE LISTING 1**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CarPriceComparison.Models
{
    public class VehicleRepository : IVehicleRepository
    {
        private VehicleContext _vehicleContext;
        public VehicleRepository(VehicleContext dbContext_)
        {
            _vehicleContext = dbContext_;
        }
        public IEnumerable<VehicleMake> GetAllMakes()
        {
            return _vehicleContext.VehicleMakes.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**CODE LISTING 2**

```
namespace CarPriceComparison.Models
{
    public class VehicleContext : DbContext
    {
        private IConfigurationRoot _config;
        public VehicleContext(IConfigurationRoot config_, DbContextOptions 
  options_) : base(options_)
        {
            _config = config_;    
        }

        public DbSet<VehicleMake> VehicleMakes {get; set;}

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config["ConnectionStrings:VehicleContextConnection"]);    
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<VehicleModel>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Make)
            .WithMany(b => b.Models)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.VehicleMakeForeignKey)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }

    }
}
```

**CODE LISTING 3**

```
private VehicleContext _vehicleContext;
        private IMailService _mailService;
        private IConfigurationRoot _config;

    public HomeController(IMailService mailService_, IConfigurationRoot 
    config_, VehicleContext vehicleContext_)
    {
        _vehicleContext = vehicleContext_;
        _mailService = mailService_;
        _config = config_;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var vehicleData = _vehicleContext.VehicleMakes.ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missing an using statement.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Thom - thanks for the info - I'll try later on today - if this fixes it I'll mark your suggestion as the answer. Thx!